# Android: how can I redirect to a fragment class on button click in main activity file?

Tags: android-button

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    final Context context = this;
    inquiry = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnInquiry);
    link = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLink);
    inquiry.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(context,QuickInquiry.class);
           startActivity(i);
       }
    });
    link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context,PortfolioFragment.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

When I click on the `button` which should open the fragment, I get an `exception` that `PortfolioFragment` is not mentioned in the `android manifest` file. `PortfolioFragment` is the fragment `java` file.

Comment: I am suffering with same problem..If u have any solution then please tell me

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Activity with startActivity().

From Android Documentation,

> A Fragment represents a behavior or a portion of user interface in an
>   Activity. You can combine multiple fragments in a single activity to
>   build a multi-pane UI and reuse a fragment in multiple activities. You
>   can think of a fragment as a modular section of an activity, which has
>   its own lifecycle, receives its own input events, and which you can
>   add or remove while the activity is running (sort of like a "sub
>   activity" that you can reuse in different activities).

Here's a detailed explanation of Fragments:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html